# How to force a LiveCard to be visible until dismissed

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm building a heads up display for OBD data (speed, RPM, throttle position etc.) using Glass.

I am using a LiveCard to display the HUD, but like all cards it fades away after a few seconds as Glass puts the display to sleep.

Is there a way to force the card to remain visible until it's dismissed?  A HUD display isn't very useful if it keeps needing to be woken up.

The code thus far is here:  https://github.com/mpicco/glass-obd-hud.

Thanks,

Marty

Answer (score 1):

I'd would recommend using an Immersion + the [`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) flag or getting a [partial wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) within your `Service`.

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
// ..screen will stay on during this section..
wl.release();
```

If you do use the wakelock solution, do not forget to release it once your `Service` is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this is inside the activity that I wish to keep the screen on for, I've added a window parameter like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

The power manager service would likely work just as well, but this way when the user destroys my activity or other such things, I don't have to worry about maintaining state.